# Generic GDI+ error while Drawing GIF file

Tags: image-processing, hex

while executing the below code, I am getting "Generic GDI+" error

```
byte[] imageByte = HexToByteArray(hexaCode); 
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

and the error is occuring on the third step.

Do any one know the reason?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your stream does not contain a valid image.

Comment: actually i got this image stream from Adobe framemaker, where it was in hexadecimel form, what i want to do is, remove unwanted datas from the hexa(like comments) , and add the proper header value, converting it into byte array and drowing it. this is working with other format, but for gif it is not working.